# deserialize json c# get value of variable

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone

I deserialize JSON with [Newtonsoft JSON DLL](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx). I have next JSON answer

```
string answer = getjsonnanswer(url);
JObject a = JObject.Parse(answer);
```

How can I refer to `a`, that get 615 - Its value of variable in JSON answer, but it hasn't got a name.

```
{
    "response": [615, 
    {
        "body": "Привет) как жизнь?",
        "title": "Re(2): ...",     
        "date": 1268238828,
        "uid": 10024748,
        "mid": 11056,
        "read_state": 0,
        "out":0
    }, 
    {
        "body": "Жду :)",
        "title": "Re(23): ...",
        "date": 1268238448, 
        "uid": 27495120, 
        "mid": 11045,
        "read_state": 1,
        "out":1
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the indexer to get the first item from the "response" array:

```
JObject a = JObject.Parse(answer);

var val = a["response"][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    JObject a = JObject.Parse(answer);


JsonObject a = new JsonObject(answer);
JsonArray ss = (JsonArray)a["response"];
var result = ss[0];
```

Comment: and how to find the object with a value of 615?

Comment: can you give me a exact jsonstring ?

Comment: @anant-dabhi{"response":[615,{"body":"Привет) как жизнь?","title":"Re(2):  ...",
"date":1268238828,"uid":10024748,"mid":11056,"read_state":0,"out":0},
{"body":"Жду :)","title":"Re(23):  ...","date":1268238448,"uid":27495120,
"mid":11045,"read_state":1,"out":1}]}